# Select records based on date comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of "rides" in my database. I want to display just the ones whose "date_range_end" field (which is a Date) is after the current date. In my controller I have this:

```
Ride.find(:all, :conditions => [ :date_range_end > Date.today ])
```

but that causes this error: comparison of Symbol with Date failed

So how do I perform this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Ride.where('date_range_end > ?', Date.today).all
```